# Editing the jsp content from a taglib

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, servlet-filters

I have a filter that processes a given servlet mapping and includes a JSP that holds the structure of every page.

```
servletContext.getRequestDispatcher( "/index.jsp" ).include( request, response );
```

Inside the jsp I have a custom jstl tag that handles the inclusion of another JSP portion inside the parent according to a series of rules (the inclusion is done inside the "body" tag:

```
pageContext.include( ProcessURI.getJSPLocation( request.getRequestURI() ) );
```

Inside to the latest included JSP I want to be able to write a stylesheet and append to the response. I am using a taglib for that.

```
<taglib:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css" >
</taglib:head>
```

Since the contents of the last JSP is included into the "body" tag I need to access the "head" and insert the HTML after the last item (I cannot insert the stylesheet inside the "body" tag).

```
<head>
    ...
    <!-- I want to insert here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css" >
<head>
<body>
    ...
```

How would I access the processed response inside the last taglib (taglib:head) where I can edit and insert its body content into the first included jsp (/index.jsp)?

I suppose it is possible to access the response that has been processed until the given taglib call, am I correct?

I accept different ways of achieving the same result using other techniques than mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but I'd rather not even think about it... the generated content before your tag may already have been streamed to the client (response buffer size).

Comment: How do I avoid the content to be streamed to the client until the evaluation of the taglib body? It should be a way to solve this without huge performance drawbacks.

Comment: Sooner or later it will become a performance bottleneck (your application server must cache the whole response!). I'd think about redesign...

Comment: What is your suggestion to achieve same result in other ways? The goal here is to keep the head and body of the page, so I can concentrate on developing inside the body. The only exception is the stylesheet import and perhaps a few custom meta tags per include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved creating one taglib to load the file `page.jsp` and another one for `page-head.jsp`. In that way I process the data in the proper order without doing some crazy response manipulation.